# R function to subset dataframe so that non-adjacent values in a column differ by >= X (starting with the first value)

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, subset

I am looking for a function that iterates through the rows of a given column ("pos" for position, ascending) in a dataframe, and only keeps those rows whose values are at least let's say 10 different, starting with the first row.Thus it would start with the first row (and store it), and then carry on until it finds a row with a value at least 10 higher than the first, store this row, then start from this value again looking for the next >10diff one.

So far I have an R for loop that successfully finds adjacent rows at least X values apart, but it does not have the capability of looking any further than one row down, nor of stopping once it has found the given row and starting again from there.

Here is the function I have:

```
# example data frame     
df <- data.frame(x=c(1:1000), pos=sort(sample(1:10000, 1000)))

# prep function (this only checks row above)
library(dplyr)
pos.apart.subset <-  function(df, pos.diff) {
  # create new dfs to store output
  new.df <- list()
  new.df1 <- data.frame()
  # iterate through each row of df
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    # if the value of next row is higher or equal than value or row i+posdiff, keep
    # if not ascending, keep
    # if first row, keep
    if(isTRUE(df$pos[i+1] >= df$pos[i]+pos.diff | df$pos[i+1] < df$pos[i] | i==1 )) {
      # add rows that meet conditions to list
      new.df[[i]] <- df[i,] }
  }
  # bind all rows that met conditions
  new.df1 <- bind_rows(new.df)
  return(new.df1)}

# test run for  pos column adjacent values to be at least 10 apart 
df1 <- pos.apart.subset(df, 10); head(df1)
```

Happy to do this in awk or any other language. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I misunderstood the question earlier since we don't want to calculate the difference between consecutive rows, you can try :

```
nrows <- 1
previous_match <- 1
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  if(df$pos[i] - df$pos[previous_match] > 10) {
    nrows <- c(nrows, i)
    previous_match <- i
   }
 }
```

and then subset the selected rows :

```
df[nrows, ]
```

---

**Earlier answer**

We can use `diff` to get the difference between consecutive rows and select the row which has difference of greater than 10.

```
head(subset(df, c(TRUE, diff(pos) > 10)))

#    x pos
#1   1   1
#2   2  31
#6   6  71
#9   9 134
#10 10 151
#13 13 185
```

The first `TRUE` is to by default select the first row.

In `dplyr`, we can use `lag` to get value from previous row :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(pos - lag(pos, default = -Inf) > 10)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers. The problem is that I dont just want to grab consecutive rows that have a difference higher than 10, I want to grab any row that has a difference of more than 10 to the first one, and then more than 10 to the second selected row, and these are unlikely to be consecutive. So something like a cumulative difference perhaps would work (thanks for the ideas though, getting closer)